# How to run vowpal-wabbit utl scripts?

Tags: machine-learning, lda, vowpalwabbit

I have installed vowpal-wabbit on my mac using `brew install vowpal-wabbit`.

The `vw` command works fine. I however want to use some of the scripts in the `\utl\` [folder of the library.](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Latent-Dirichlet-Allocation#friendly-wrapper-utility-to-vw---lda)

Specifically I want to run [vw_lda.py](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/utl/vw-lda)

I tried copying this script to my machine and running it but I get the following error:

`reading dataset...
ERROR: vw-doc2lda not found in the path`

Turns out `vw-doc2lda` is another script in the utl folder which script cannot run. I tried copying vw-doc2lda also to my local machine and adding its path to `$PATH`. It still can't find the script.

How do I run the scripts in the utl folder?

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to change permission to make the utl files executable first and add the utl directory to path.